# Returning a 403 from a webapi2 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

My API has the following routes

GET: api/departments

GET: api/departments/{departmentID}/employees

The second route maps to the following controller action

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int departmentID)
{
  return GetEmployees(departmentID);
}
```

This route can potentially be called with a departmentID that does not exist or that the user does not have permission to access. When this happens, what is the proper way to handle it? Currently, I have modified my controller action to return a 403 as shown below

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int departmentID)
{
  var isDepartmentValid = CheckIfDepartmentIsAccessible(username, departmentID);
  if(!isDepartmentValid)
  {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
  }

   Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, GetEmployees(departmentID));
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? It seems like the change in method signature makes it harder to understand the content type returned from the controller action. Is there a way to have the method signature remain the same but still return a 403 if needed?

Comment: I would actually recommend throwing a 404 instead of a 403 if the dept doesn't exist, and a 403 if it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add onto Rob Davis's answer I would recommend doing this this way so you don't need to change the signature of your method and the returned response is more meaningful to the client:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int departmentID)
{
   try
   {
      return GetEmployees(departmentID);
   }
   catch(Exception ex) //assuming invalid dept or unauthorized throw Argument & Security Exceptions respectively
   {
        if(ex is SecurityException)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        else if(ex is ArgumentException)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        else
             //handle or throw actual unhandled exception
    }
}
```

This assumes that you're using exceptions, but obviously any other type of check can be done to see if the dept exists or if they have access.  Then return the correct response.  Since this is a WebAPI the performance loss will be negligible since your biggest bottleneck will most likely be the network itself.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int departmentID)
{
    var isDepartmentValid = CheckIfDepartmentIsAccessible(username, departmentID);
    if (!isDepartmentValid)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, GetEmployees(departmentID));
}
```

Comment: I did find this solution online but skipped over it for performance reasons although I may be wrong. Does throwing an unhandled exception affect performance and scalability down the line?

Comment: @user1 Using an HttpResponseException may technically reduce performance, but not significantly enough that I would avoid this path.  It does not appear that you're creating a real-time performance application and therefore the slow down will be negligible.   This will not actually be an unhandled exception since the ASP.NET pipeline will handle it and return the http response code that you want to send back.

Answer (score 0):

To me the best place to put all sorts of authentication/authorization would be either in the OWIN middleware or some Authorize action filters; but depends on your requirements because if you don't have any more routes that require auth I would possibly leave the solution as it is and have the check inside the controller action itself.

Comment: How do you validate controller parameters inside the OWIN middleware?